# Is that possible to know last updated column form a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

So i accidentally updated all my data in a column form a table, i have already restored it with my backup table, but the problem is that the backup up table is not containing the latest data, is there possible to view track record from my table that containing timestamp every time that column have been updated ?

I have already tried to generate a query, but the result only showing modified date if we altered the column not updated the value of the column

```
SELECT a.object_id,
       b.name,
       a.last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats a,
     sys.objects b
WHERE a.object_id = b.object_id
  AND b.name = 'INSERT_MAP'
ORDER BY last_user_update DESC;
```

Comment: Unless you're storing the information of "what changed" *somewhere*, be that with Data Change Auditing, History Tables, Temporal Data, 3rd party software, then you won't know *what* changed.

Comment: On a completely different note, the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax has been around for 27 years; it's past time you start using it. Also, `a` is bad alias for `dm_db_index_usage_stats` and `b` is too for `sys.objects`; it starts with `o`. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) & [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). I also recommend good use of White Space and line breaks for readable code.

Comment: If you really need to be able to roll back to a specific point, look at transaction log back ups. Also, learn from your mistake and **always** check your `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Not just checking your update statement but putting them into an explicit transaction with a rollback at first so you can ensure the update is really what you want. Too late for that this time around but arm yourself for next time.